# HICON to BufferedImage makes the jvm crash on 64 bit

Tags: java, 64-bit, gdi, jna, jvm-crash

Im using this method to get a BufferedImage from HICON

```
public BufferedImage getIcon(Pointer hIcon) {
    int   width =16;
    int   height=16;
    short depth =24;
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    byte[] lpBitsColor = new byte[width*height*depth/8];
    byte[] lpBitsMask  = new byte[width*height*depth/8];
    BITMAPINFO info     = new BITMAPINFO();
    BITMAPINFOHEADER hdr= new BITMAPINFOHEADER();
    info.bmiHeader   =hdr;
    hdr.biWidth      =width;
    hdr.biHeight     =height;
    hdr.biPlanes     =1;
    hdr.biBitCount   =depth;
    hdr.biCompression=BI_RGB;

    Pointer hDC =u32.GetDC(null);
    ICONINFO piconinfo = new ICONINFO();
    u32.GetIconInfo(hIcon, piconinfo);
    gdi32.GetDIBits(hDC, piconinfo.hbmColor, 0, height, lpBitsColor, info, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
    gdi32.GetDIBits(hDC, piconinfo.hbmMask , 0, height, lpBitsMask , info, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    int r, g, b, a, argb;
    int x=0, y=height-1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lpBitsColor.length; i=i+3) {
        b =      lpBitsColor[i  ] & 0xFF;
        g =      lpBitsColor[i+1] & 0xFF;
        r =      lpBitsColor[i+2] & 0xFF;
        a = 0xFF-lpBitsMask [i  ] & 0xFF;
        //System.out.println(lpBitsMask[i]+" "+lpBitsMask[i+1]+" "+lpBitsMask[i+2]);
        argb= (a<<24) | (r<<16) | (g<<8) | b;       
        image.setRGB(x, y, argb);
        x=(x+1)%width;
        if (x==0) y--;
    }

    u32.ReleaseDC(null, hDC);

    return image;
}
```

The method work like a charm when i change the build path to 32bit jre,
but when the build path is on 64bit jre and trying to debug it the JVM crash with access violation on this line:

```
gdi32.GetDIBits(hDC, piconinfo.hbmColor, 0, height, lpBitsColor, info, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
```

previews native calls worked fine,but when trying access gdi32.dll (on its 64 bit version (located in system32)) on this method its crash.

im running windows 7 64bit machine

Thanks

Comment: This is usually because one or more of your arguments is of an incorrect size (32- vs 64-bit), or the field definitions for your structures are not appropriate for both architectures.